# Can't figure it out, why is this answer is right. By what pattern

Tags: pattern-recognition

I found this example in some old book and can't figure it out, why is this answer is right. Would like to get an explanation to it. Thanks in advance.

I don't have reputation over 10, so I uploaded image to some other host, hope it won't be a problem to you, here it is:
[image]
http://postimg.org/image/auf1el5fz/

and also sorry for tags, I don't know where is it belong

Comment: I *could* explain *some* distinguishing features, but only *ex post*, and don't see anything compelling to prefer 1 over 6.

Comment: Also, I'd have a very nice explanation why 5 would be correct :)

Comment: This is eating my brain from yesterday and I can't figure out why is this answer is correct :)

Comment: What are your ideas so far? If you ignore the stretching/squashing, the shapes are being rotated by $45$ degrees and then $90$ degrees as they go down columns. $1$ is the only one that fits this- but it doesn't seem satisfactory to just ignore the stretching/squashing!

Comment: How can we tell which answer is correct, when there isn't a question that has been asked?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it is more appropriate for [Puzzling Stack Exchange](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Based on rotation of the dot and larger shape in other columns, I would have expected 2 rotated $45^\circ$ clockwise) in the middle right cell, and 4 rotated through $90^\circ$ clockwise in the bottom right cell. Is it possible the question is testing the executive brain function involved in finding a best-fit rule that explains 2 out of 3 aspects (rotation of the dot and a symmetry axis though the dot, but not the stretching/squashing), then cutting your losses by moving on the next question?!

Answer (score 0):

The choice of 1 or 6 is clear based on structure and repetition.
Observing the position of the black point makes the selection of 1 somewhat preferable when compared the positions selected.
So number 1 is the most appropriate selection.

Answer (score 0):

First Column:
2 stretched 1 squashed
1st: base picture
2nd: rotated 45° right and squashed
3rd: rotated 90° right and stretched
Second Column:
2 squashed 1 stretched
1st: base picture (already squashed)
2nd: rotated right 45° and stretched
3rd: rotated right 90° and stretched
Third Column:
2 stretched 1 squashed
1st: base picture
2nd: rotated right 45°
3rd: rotated right 90° and squashed
Dot is always affected by rotation (no idea why in column 2 3rd the dot is  squashed tho)
This would be the predominant pattern